# How to split an existing eclipse dynamic web project into web, jar, and webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have la large Eclipse project ( Dynamic Web Pages, using tomcat), and need to split it in three projects with dependencies:

- The application proper, providing web pages through tomcat
- A relatively static part, shared with other projects, preferably becoming a JAR (sort of framework)
- A web service, publishing some of the application functionality, through axis14 and tomcat

My question is how to define these three projects so that dependencies are handled automatically by eclipse, while being able to debug them combined ?

-- I'm using Eclipse Helios Java EE R1 in windows vista 32bits

Comment: You can easily define a Web project with dependencies on a JAR project. The problem is thinking that the Web project must have dependencies on your Web Service project (through another Web project, EJB, that relies on your design). The best way to do this will be to define the dependencies through the WSDL file.

Comment: Right, Luiggi, after further diggig, I found how to split a project into source and framework(jar), on the eclipse help topic "Project using a source framework with restricted access".   Plus, its necessary to insert the framework project in the source project build path "Projects" tag. Thanks ! – artejera